# Pass model Property to Razor View Component

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, view, components, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm working on the Razor View components and I used below code to define view component.

View :

```
@using MyLibrary.Models
@model InputComponentModel

<label asp-for=@Model.model class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.model class="form-control" type=@Model.Type />
<span asp-validation-for=@Model.model class="text-danger"></span>
```

Component :

```
 public class TextInput
{
    public TextInput(ComponentType type)
    {
            ComponentType = type
    }

    private ComponentType ComponentType { get;}

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string id, ModelExpression for)
    {
        InputComponentModel model = new()
        {
            FieldId = id,
            Type = ComponentType,
            model = for.Model

        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

InputComponentModel :

```
 public class InputComponentModel
    {
        public ComponentType Type { get; set; }
        public string FieldId { get; set; }

        public object model { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I used this view component in my view as follows

```
@model Web.Models.RegisterModel

 <vc:text-input id="username" for="username"></vc:text-input>
```

But when I run this code, I got null value for "for.Model". I want to pass this "RegisterModel" model username property to my View Component.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pass `@Model.UserName` to ViewComponent:

```
 <vc:text-input id="username" username=@Model.UserName></vc:text-input>
```

ViewComponent:

```
public class TextInput
{
    public TextInput(ComponentType type)
    {
            ComponentType = type
    }

    private ComponentType ComponentType { get;}

    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string id, string username)
        {
            InputComponentModel model = new()
            {
                FieldId = id,
                Type = ComponentType,
                model = username
    
            };
            return View(model);
        }
}
```